# Understanding code to reverse string

Tags: c++

I am struggling to understand the code below which is used to reverse a null-terminated string. I have written comments explaining the lines I am struggling to understand.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str)     // I don't understand what is happening within this if loop and how this is carried out for `str` which is not Boolean
    {
        while (*end) // I dont know what this means either
        {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;

        while (str < end)
        {
            tmp = *str
                *str++ = *end //I am confused as to why this is not just *str = *end
                *end-- = tmp; //Similarly, why is this not *end = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesAdkison I left the extra indentation in the second while loop to show off the code is missing semi-colons.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be a really nasty bug if it doesn't just cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis yes it would.  I just didn't want to modify the OP's code but fix the indentation as it was flat when posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `if (str)`  means
   Check if `str` a pointer to `char` is not NULL. Same as: `if (str != NULL)`
2. `while (*end)` check that the `char` pointed to by `end` is not the null-terminating character. Same as: `while (*end != '\0')`
3. `*str++ = *end`  Assign the `char` pointed to by `end` to `str` and then advance `str` pointer by 1 char. `*end--` advances `end` backwards by 1 char.
4. `while (str < end)` Compare the addresses as numbers (and not the values the pointers point to). This only makes sense if both pointers refer to different positions in the same memory block e.g. a c string in this case or any array. If `str` points to the 1st element of the string and `end` to the 2nd, then `str < end` will be true. The actuals chars in the 1st and 2nd positions will are not taken into account

Comment: May I ask one further question. I understand the purpose of `while (str < end)`, which is when the two pointers meet in the middle. But I am struggling to understand what exactly is being compared as these are two pointers. Thanks.

Comment: added comments in my actual answer

Answer (score 0):

`*end = str;` means the value of `end` pointer contains characters of string `str`

`if (str)` means check if `str` pointer isn't `null` ,so it's always `true` when `str` point to char.

`while (*end)`  means check if `end` points to char , when pointer is `null` the condition is terminated , so when pointer reach the end of string `end`, `while` condition break and `end` pointer value contains the last char of string `end`.

`*str++ = *end`  this statement can be break down to 2 statements to understand it :

first `*str=*end;` replace char value pointed by `str` with char pointed by `end`.

second `*str++;` move pointer to next character in string `str` after replacing.

`*end-- = tmp;` this statement can be break down to 2 statements to understand it :

first `*end = tmp;` replace char value pointed by `end` with `tmp` char.

second `*end--;` move pointer to previous char in string `end` after replacing.

I hope the idea is clear for you.

Answer (score -1):

know that `*end = str;`

`end = is the pointer here`

They're checking the string if is not null if it is null ,if `is` should take the value of the char and assign to it

in your case the string is temp

i want you understand what char  temp is doing  and `*end` as pointer treat `*end` as a string meaning `*end` should not be null ,temp is character

```
while (*end) 
 ++end;
```

it is telling that while end is not null, meaning the results should be a string ( e.g. a name like john)

`--end`  it is telling you that the null should be clear 
then it should go to another while

`while (str < end)` because the string is null

take char temp  take to be a string

`*str++ = *end`    then allow characters to make it a string or a name
or increement the character to make it a string

`end-- = tmp` // they are assign the string to that null string to have a vlue